# Props in component only retrieved on reload, not from navigation

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux

I have an action that sends a Firebase query that relies on `store` data - specifically the `uid`.

The `uid` IS populated and stored upon user sign-in, which is stored in an `auth` object.

In this component, I'm retrieving the `uid`, firing the action, receiving the `payload`, updating the state with a `reducer`, and rendering the component with the data.

I've mapped the state to props thus (initially `this.props.uid` is always `undefined`):

```
function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
  return {
    uid: state.auth.uid,
    componentData: state.thisComponent.componentData
  }
}
```

I check the `uid` thus (written before `render()`):

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {    
  if (nextProps.uid !== this.props.uid) {
    this.props.actions.getComponentData(nextProps.uid)
   }
 }
```

The action and query work, but only if the component is refreshed - not if the component is simply navigated to. Additionally, I'm using `redux-persist` to hydrate the store and persist its state:

```
**index.js**
 ... combineReducers etc

 let store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk), autoRehydrate());
 persistStore(store)
```

How do I make sure that `componentWillReceiveProps` always dispatches the action and the payload is rendered - whether the page is opened from  a different link or when it is refreshed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentWillReceiveProps` is not run when the component is mounted, it is only run, like you say, after initialization and when the component will receive a new set of props.

I believe you are looking for `componentWillMount`, anything put in here will run before the component is mounted, meaning, this life-cycle event is invoked immediately before the `render` method.

```
componentWillMount(props) {    
   props.actions.getComponentData(props.uid)
}
```

Take a look at http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/ for more information

Depending on your use case you might need it on both.

Comment: thanks... i used `componentWillMount` on it's own but that didn't work - so combining the two did the job.